# 404 when trying to get response from backend using axios

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

I am trying to get function result from backend to frontend via axios but it returns 404 every time.

I managed to send request to backend and activate function but on geting result it started returning 404

route in app.ts

```
import cardRoute from './routes/test';
const app = express();
app.use('/test', cardRoute);
```

./routes/test.ts (backend)

function test_load() returns string

```
import express from 'express';
import { test_load }  from '../cardpull';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('./test-bed',
  async (req, res) => {
  let cards = test_load()
  res.send(cards);
},
);

export default router;
```

Frontend call

```
async function GetCard() {
    var cards = await axios.post<string>('/test/test-bed');
    return cards;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

your route is not valid

```
router.post('./test-bed',
  async (req, res) => {
  let cards = test_load()
  res.send(cards);
},
);
```

should be:

```
router.post('/test-bed',
  async (req, res) => {
  let cards = test_load()
  res.send(cards);
},
);
```

and on your axios URL, maybe you need to include the host and port because if you define only the endpoint, it will hit your frontend host and port,
example if you open express on `localhost:3000`
then the axios will be
`axios.post('http://localhost:3000/test/test-bed')`

note: I didn't write the answer with typescript, but with javascript style should be clear enough.

Comment: The thing is, i can call function at button press, activate it on backend so route is working, but i can't recieve anything from it due to weird 404.

Comment: 404 page not found means that your axios didn't find any file or response from that route, did you test your backend route with Postman yet?

Comment: Ok so i got rid of 404 error, but it still wont pass data to frontend

Comment: what is the error? CORS ?

Comment: There is no error it's just not doing anything, it passes request and function executes cuz i see it on backend terminal, but then backend doesn't do anything to send data back.

Comment: try to check the browser devtool 'Console' section for error, or you can see the request and response of the request  on 'Network' section.

Comment: No errors on browser console, no anything request just enters to backend and executes and frontned get's nothing in respons, on backend console ther also is none errors.

Comment: If there is no error trace then you must debug it yourself. It is hard to debug things without a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The router must return a json response or a status code.
Hope it helps.